# Equivalent Javascript code for Applescript code

Tags: javascript, applescript

What is the equivalent of the AppleScript code, shown below, in JavaScript?

```
tell application "Safari"
    open POSIX file "/Users/asuvathdhamank/Desktop/Asuvath/index.html"
end tell
```

Comment: `window.open("file:///Users/asuvathdhamank/Desktop/Asuvath/index.html")`?

Answer (score 0):

Tested in **Script Editor**, with the **[Script language]** *popup menu* set to **JavaScript**, the following example code style worked for me:

```javascript
var app = Application('Safari');
app.open("/Users/asuvathdhamank/Desktop/Asuvath/index.html");
```